# XML validation with C#

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

Good day folks!
I am having some issues trying to get an XML file validated against it's schema.
The XML file I have looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<game:gameXML xmlns:game="national:game" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Header>
    <From description="Gamer">Gamer</From>
    <To description="Player">Player</To>
    <MessageId>1620711716</MessageId>
    <MessageDate>2021-05-11T15:41:53</MessageDate>
    <TransactionGroup>Ball</TransactionGroup>
    <Priority>Medium</Priority>
    <SecurityContext>CONTACT_PERSON_GOES_HERE</SecurityContext>
    <Market>Japan</Market>
  </Header>
  <Transactions>
    <Transaction transaction="1620711716">
      <ReportRequest>
        <ReportParameters xsi:type="game:reportParameters">
          <ReportName>All</ReportName>
          <FromDate>2005-01-01</FromDate>
          <ToDate>2021-05-11</ToDate>    
        </ReportParameters>
      </ReportRequest>
    </Transaction>
  </Transactions>
</game:gameXML>
```

I used VS 2019 to generate the corresponding schema, which gives me this:

**xmlFile.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:game="national:game" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="national:game" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:import schemaLocation="xmlContent.xsd" />
    <xs:element name="gameXML">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Header" />
                <xs:element ref="Transactions" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

and

**xmlContent.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Header">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="From">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:simpleContent>
                            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                <xs:attribute name="description" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                            </xs:extension>
                        </xs:simpleContent>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="To">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:simpleContent>
                            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                <xs:attribute name="description" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                            </xs:extension>
                        </xs:simpleContent>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="MessageId" type="xs:unsignedInt" />
                <xs:element name="MessageDate" type="xs:dateTime" />
                <xs:element name="TransactionGroup" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="Priority" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="SecurityContext" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="Market" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Transactions">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Transaction">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="ReportRequest">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="ReportParameters">
                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                <xs:sequence>
                                                    <xs:element name="ReportName" type="xs:string" />
                                                    <xs:element name="FromDate" type="xs:date" />
                                                    <xs:element name="ToDate" type="xs:date" />
                                                </xs:sequence>
                                            </xs:complexType>
                                        </xs:element>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute name="transaction" type="xs:unsignedInt" use="required" />
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The code I am using to load these is:

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings { DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse };
XmlSchemaSet xs = new XmlSchemaSet();
xs.Add("national:game", "xmlFile.xsd");
xs.Add("national:game", "xmlContent.xsd");
xs.Compile();
```

As soon as I run this it explodes with error:

```
System.Exception: This is an invalid xsi:type 'national:game:reportParameters'.
```

Clearly it is injecting the namespace into the `xmlContent.xsd` file and I can't figure out what needs to be set to prevent this. In fact, this .xsd file should have it's own namespace (see `<ReportParameters xsi:type="game:reportParameters">` in the actual .xml file).

Any clues, pointers or help would be tremendously appreciated.
**Thank you.**

Comment: I get a completely different error to you - `System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaException: 'The 'Header' element is not declared.'` - this is the first opportunity I've had to try to run your code. I have copied each code sample exactly. Furthermore the type annotation you mention as the problem is in the instance document, and you haven't mentioned any code that validates against the compiled XmlSchemaSet, so this is not reproducible with the information given. I can see that the `ref="Header"` declaration is not being recognised, and I'd appreciate you providing the code that got you past that.

Answer (score 0):

None of your types are named, so it looks as though there are no valid values for `xsi:type` besides the schema built-in types because all the complexTypes are anonymous.

This is one respect where xsd.exe (the tool used to generate schemas) is limited, since by definition if an xsi:type attribute is present it must refer to some type declared by the schema, but the generated schema declares no named types. However its purpose is to resolve ambiguity, so it wouldn't be logical for that same tool to introduce ambiguity.

To fix this, restructure `xmlContent.xsd` to declare the `reportParameters` type globally and reference it i.e.

```
<xs:element name="ReportParameters" type="game:reportParameters"/>

<xs:complexType name="reportParameters">
...
```

Comment: Thank you @Tom. Does not work though:
System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaException: Cannot load the schema from the location 'xmlContent.xsd' - The value for the 'type' attribute is invalid - 'game:reportParameters' is an invalid value for the 'type' attribute.

Furthermore, the "name" attribute is not allowed in "xs:complexType"

Comment: On the second error, I don't know what to tell you because I've used it many times so know with 100% certainty that it's right. Maybe check with the [XML Schema spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/) that all your elements are declared correctly. I'll stand by the principle of my answer, that xsi:type requires a named type and the schema generator isn't sophisticated enough to be able to handle this.

Comment: The second error I'm not so sure about but looks like it would be a consequence of the first; if the complexType it is meant to refer to is wrong in some way, then it won't be referencing a valid name.